# PowerShell function to find word within string

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking for a way to export words out of a string using PowerShell. I wrote a function that spits out the position of each character starting with capital letters:

```
function Get-WordList {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param(
    [string]$InputString
  )

  $WordList = $inputString -csplit '\W+|(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])'


  Return ($WordList | Select-Object -Unique)
}
```

I have tested this with strings like:

```
Get-WordList -InputString "DeviceManagementGroup"
Get-WordList -InputString "SG-AD-XYZ-8021xAuth"
Get-WordList -InputString "Azure ATP mylab Viewers"
Get-WordList -InputString "SG-AZ-XYZ-MDM-WindowsBYOD-Devices-DYN"
Get-WordList -InputString "SG-AZ-XYZ-Entra-M365E5Licensed-Users"
Get-WordList -InputString "SG-AZ-UserGrp-Microsoft365ServiceAccounts"
Get-WordList -InputString "SG-AZ-UserGrp-AzureServiceAccounts"
Get-WordList -InputString "SG-AZ-DynDeviceGrp-Autopilot-AADJTagged"
```

This works almost 100% of the time, except when it comes to multiple capitals in a row. In the last example, the there is AADJTagged. It sees it as one word where I am tying to split it up like:

*Get-WordList -InputString "SG-AZ-DynDeviceGrp-Autopilot-AADJTagged"*

```
SG
AZ
Dyn
Device
Grp
Autopilot
AADJ
Tagged
```

Instead it is like this:

```
SG
AZ
Dyn
Device
Grp
Autopilot
AADJTagged
```

I know I'm missing something in the regex like a positive lookahead for lowercase...any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
(?<!^|[- ])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[- ]
```

Output

```
SG, AZ, Dyn, Device, Grp, Autopilot, AADJ, Tagged
Device, Management, Group
SG, AD, XYZ, 8021x, Auth
Azure, ATP, mylab, Viewers
SG, AZ, XYZ, MDM, WindowsBYOD, Devices, DYN
SG, AZ, XYZ, Entra, M365E5, Licensed, Users
SG, AZ, User, Grp, Microsoft365, Service, Accounts
SG, AZ, User, Grp, Azure, Service, Accounts
SG, AZ, Dyn, Device, Grp, Autopilot, AADJ, Tagged
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a "word" must start with a capital letter, this matches them:

`([A-Z](?![a-z0-9])){2,}|[A-Z][a-z0-9]*`

So it's trying for 2 matches:

1. 2 or more consecutive capital letters, which aren't followed by [a-z0-9] (or a capital letter), because that would be the beginning of a new word.
2. 1 capital letter, followed by any amount of [a-z0-9]

What are your rules with numbers? Do "-2-", "-A2-", "-2A-", "-2a-", "-a2-"... contain words? Let me know if you have any further specifications or more test cases to consider.

Code:

```
function Get-WordList {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)][String] $InputString
    )

    $Pattern = '([A-Z](?![a-z0-9])){2,}|[A-Z][a-z0-9]*'
    $Result = $InputString | Select-String -AllMatches -CaseSensitive -Pattern $Pattern
    Return $Result.Matches.Value | Select -Unique
}

Get-WordList @'
SG-AZ-DynDeviceGrp-Autopilot-AADJTagged
DeviceManagementGroup
SG-AD-XYZ-8021xAuth
Azure ATP mylab Viewers
SG-AZ-XYZ-MDM-WindowsBYOD-Devices-DYN
SG-AZ-XYZ-Entra-M365E5Licensed-Users
SG-AZ-UserGrp-Microsoft365ServiceAccounts
SG-AZ-UserGrp-AzureServiceAccounts
'@
```

Output:

```
SG
AZ
Dyn
Device
Grp
Autopilot
AADJ
Tagged
Management
Group
AD
XYZ
Auth
Azure
ATP
Viewers
MDM
Windows
BYOD
Devices
DYN
Entra
M365
E5
Licensed
Users
User
Microsoft365
Service
Accounts
```

Comment: When I added that regex to the -csplit; the output for "SG-AZ-XYZ-Entra-M365E5Licensed-Users" is broken into this. 

G
-
Z
-
Z
-
-
365
5
-

If I try the other examples, I get the same issue. How did you get it to output?

Comment: Sorry totally forgot, this is using Select-String with a matching pattern, instead of splitting the non-matching parts. Added some code. Let me know if it works and also reputation would be appreciated if it does ;)

Comment: Updated it to handle numbers better

Comment: oh yeah this does work well! its pretty responsive too! Thanks.

Comment: I did see that the Microsoft365 isn't broken up...but not sure if I like it to or not. I will need to test it with my mapping script

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to do the trick:

```
\W+|(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])|\W+|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})
```

There might be a cleaner regex, but this is the best that I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**:

- The solution below builds on your approach based on `-csplit`, the case-sensitive variant of PowerShell's [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)- operator, and therefore also outputs words that contain no uppercase letter at all.
- By using `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` (consistently), *all* uppercase and lowercase letters are matched, not just *English* (ASCII-range) letters (`[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`).<sup>[*]</sup>

---

A **more readable and maintainable alternative to [your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77553117/45375)** that takes advantage of [inline regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) `(?x)` (`IgnorePatternWhitespace`), which allows use of incidental whitespace and to-end-of-line comments with `#`, for better readability:

```bash
$regex = @'
(?x) # Split by any (|) of the following subexpressions:
  \W+ | # nonempty run of non-word characters such as spaces and "-"
  (?<=\w)(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll}) |   # *at* UPPER followed by lower, *if preceded by* a word char. (i.e. word-internal)
  (?<=[\p{Ll}\d])(?=\p{Lu}) | # *at* UPPER, *if preceded by* lower or digit
  (?<=\p{Ll})(?=\d)           # *at* digit, *if preceded by* lower
'@

$sampleString = @'
AB-ATP mylab-snakeCase-CamelCase-upperLAST--aclU-AADJTagged
8021xAuth-Microsoft365ServiceAccounts-M365E5
'@

$sampleString -csplit $regex
```

- This matches the behavior of your `Get-WordList` function with the desired enhancement: breaking word such as `AADJTagged` into `AADJ` and `Tagged`.
- Digit handling hasn't been changed, which means `M365E5` is split into `M365` and `E5`, based on the inferred rule that only a *lowercase* letter preceding a digit should cause a split at the digit.
- It should be straightforward to tweak the subexpressions and add new ones, if necessary - note that the `(?x)` inline option must remain *at the very start* of the first line in the enclosing verbatim [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) literal.
- For a **more detailed explanation** of the regex and the **option to experiment** with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/8vZYlb/7).

  - The following screenshot shows all the matching separator *spans* (blue) (matching `\W+`) and *positions* (pink) (matching the subsequent subexpressions based on [*lookaround assertions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#lookarounds-at-a-glance)).

    - [image: regex101.com screenshot]

Output in the PowerShell console:

```
AB
ATP
mylab
snake
Case
Camel
Case
upper
LAST
acl
U
AADJ
Tagged
8021x
Auth
Microsoft
365
Service
Accounts
M365
E5
```

---

<sup>[*] Expressions such as `\p{Lu}` for an uppercase character are [Unicode character *categories*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories). Note that additional letter categories exist beyond upper- and lowercase, such as `\p{Lt}` for *title-case* letters.</sup>

Comment: This does work; it will break up the Microsoft365 into two. I never saw the (?x) before which is interesting. Something I saw different with mine: '\W+|(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])|\W+|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})' is that will even break up the M365E5 into two which I kind of like.

Comment: If I use your (?x) with this, it does look cleaner: '(?x) \W+ | (?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z]) | (?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9]) | (?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})'

Comment: I ended up going with: '(?x) \W+ | (\p{Lu}[^\W\d\p{Lu}]+) | ((?<!\p{Lu})\p{Lu}+\b) | (?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])'. It seemed to solve both AADJTagged, M365E5, Microsoft365, etc. I will do more testing against a whole list of Azure groups to see how it outputs

Comment: @powershellcrack, it wouldn't split `AADJTagged` - and it perpetuates the awkward mix of ASCII-letters-only and Unicode-letter matching. Also, why wouldn't `M365E5`, be broken into `M`, `365`, `E`, and `5`? I think you need to get clarity on the exact rules; the solution in this answer satisfies all the rules implied by your question.

Comment: @powershellcrack, I've reworked the regex substantially and improved its readability. If it still doesn't do exactly what you want (around the handling of digits), it shouldn't be hard to tweak it.